# How to apply hibernate annotations to the child class of abstract class

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, orm

I have an abstract class named **Staff**. **Instructor** and **Lecturer** are the derived classes from the **Staff** superclasses. I need to use hibernate annotations into the **Instructor** and **Lecturer** classes.

**Staff.java**

```
public abstract class Staff {
    private int staffID;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String mobile;
    private String email;
    private double salary;
    private String city;
    private String street;

    //getters and setters
}
```

This is the subclass and I used **staffID** again in the subclass to apply the **@Id** annotation.

**Lecturer.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "lecturer")
public class Lecturer extends Staff {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int staffID;

    private int lectureHours;

    public int getLectureHours() {
        return lectureHours;
    }

    public void setLectureHours(int lectureHours) {
        this.lectureHours = lectureHours;
    }
}
```

I used the service classes and controllers and the JPARepositories as usually. but the database table only contain 2 values fields only (staffID and lectureHours). as follows.

[image]

**LecturerRepository.java**

```
package com.example.backend.admin.Repositories;

import com.example.backend.admin.models.Lecturer;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface LecturerRepository extends JpaRepository<Lecturer, Integer> {

}
```

**LecturerController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/lecturers")
public class LecturerController {
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LecturerController.class);
    @Autowired
    LecturerService lecturerService;

    /**
     * to insert a new lecturer
     * @param lecturer new lecturer
     * @return insert lecturer
     */
    @PostMapping("/add")
    public Lecturer addLecturer(@RequestBody Lecturer lecturer) {
        Lecturer lecturer1 = null;
        try {
            lecturer1 = lecturerService.addLecturer(lecturer);
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            logger.error("check the payload, null pointer is throwing", e);
        }
        return lecturer1;
    }
}
```

**LecturerService.java**

```
@Service
public class LecturerService {
    @Autowired
    LecturerRepository lecturerRepository;

    /**
     * to invoke save method in jpa
     * @param lecturer new lecturer
     * @return inserted lecturer
     */
    public Lecturer addLecturer(Lecturer lecturer){
        return lecturerRepository.save(lecturer);
    }
}
```

I want to add all the fields of the **Lecturer** class into the database. So what should I do for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to annotate the abstract class with `@MappedSuperclass`, in this way your `@Entity` class will inherit all the attributes from the extended class.